# Shape whose translated and scaled copies are closed under intersection

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, convexity

The translated and scaled copies of an equilateral triangle with fixed orientation are closed under intersection - the intersection is again an equilateral triangle with the same orientation.

[image: Two intersecting equilateral triangles]

What other convex shapes in 2D have this property?

Comment: Don't know if these count as a shapes but this also holds for single points, lines and line segments.

Comment: it holds for any triangle not just equilateral ones.

Comment: @Dirk I would prefer shapes with non-zero area.

Comment: @user35593 You're right! I don't know how I overlooked that...

Comment: The empty set is a possible intersection. Do you allow something like the set of points with rational coordinates within a triangle as a shape?

Comment: @DouglasZare I want the shape to be convex. I'll update the question to mention this.

Comment: It seems to be (quite vaguely) related to the concept of _generating sets_ in differential games --- namely, such sets that any  (nonempty) their translates' intersection is a Minkowski summand of the set itself; see, e.e., this paper: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=1481&option_lang=eng

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think triangles (degenerated ones included) are the only such convex shapes. The idea is: If $C$ is such a convex shape, let  $p_i\in\partial C$ for $i=1,2,3$ be three [smooth points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_cone#Definition_in_convex_geometry). One  can obtain an approximate triangle as an intersection of three large copies $C$, say $m(C-p_i)+p_i$ for large $m$. Since these intersections are similar to $C$, and converge to a triangle as $m\to\infty$, $C$ itself is  a triangle.

Comment: (Note that since ∂C is convex, all points but at most countably many are smooth. Also note, the analogous statement and proof   hold true in any dimension )

Answer (score 3):

Since the shape $A$ is convex its boundary is differentiable almost everywhere. Take a point $p$ where it is differentiable. A line $l$ is tangent to A in $p$. Take two more points $q_1$ and $q_2$ with tangent lines $l_1$ and $l_2$, translate the shape by vectors $q-q_1$ and $q-q_2$ and intersect results. Suppose we get a shape $B$. The only point which can possibly have a tangent line parallel to $l$ will be $p$, but $\partial B$ is not differentiable there (unless all lines are parallel). Therefore, $B$ is not a homothetic image of $A$ and that means $B$ is at most one-dimensional.

[image]

$B$ being one-dimensional means $\angle (l_2, l) + \angle (l, l_1) \le \pi$ (we take angles which "look" at $A$). If there is at least 5 different directions for tangent lines we get a contradiction since in a convex pentagon the sum of angles is $3\pi$ but from our inequality it must be no more than $5\pi/2$. Therefore our shape is either a triangle (for which it is true) or parallelogram (false).

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not provide a motivation for your question I do not know if the following reference is appropriate; however, you might want to look at George Stiny's book *Shape: Talking about Seeing and Doing* (Cambridge, Massachusetts: The MIT Press, 2006), in particular his discussion of closure on pp. 285-87 and p. 306.